# Auto Convert my POST API parameters to string in Sailsjs

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express, sails.js

I am implementing my API in Sails JS but I am getting an issue that when I am trying to test my API in POSTMAN, all of my parameters converted to string whether its an array or an integer.

```
let { pageSize, pageNumber, marketregion, category, fromDate, toDate, group_size } = req.body;
```

I am sending pageSize as 2 but I am receiving as "2" and ['abc']  as "['abc']".
I need help in this regard.

Comment: What you are trying to do here?, with req.body you are getting string type json object

Comment: @123Ex I am just trying to get values from req.body, For example if I am sending ['abc'] from POSTMAN, but what I received is "['abc']". Do I need to convert all my parameters manually?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [SailsJS documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-body),

> By default, the request body can be url-encoded or stringified as JSON

So yes, if you need them as integers, you'd have to convert them to integers.